# Partly managed, partly unmanaged class in java spring

Tags: java, spring

I create numerous objects of class MyClass in my code.

```
public class MyClass {

    private String a;
    private Integer b;
    private SomeObject c;

    public A(String a, Integer b, SomeObject c) {
        this.a = a; this.b = b; this.c = c;
    }

}
```

Is there anyway i can use Spring to inject just SomeObject into this class when i create an object of MyClass. MyClass is **not** spring managed as i need to create objects of the same in my code in a random manner. How i try to resolve this.

1. I do a getBean in my main method for SomeObject and pass it into MyClass whenever i am creating its objects.
2. I create a SomeObjectSingleton which is ApplicationContextAware (which itself does a getBean to get SomeObject). I directly call SomeObjectSingleton.getImpl in MyClass constructor.

Which way do you think seems most appropriate, or is there any other better way to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Spring-Managed Solution**

If you don't have a problem with making `MyClass` Spring-managed, then [you could set the `singleton` property to `false`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-modes).  That way, whenever you call `context.getBean()`, a new instance of `MyClass` will be instantiated.

Then in your context XML file, you could wire `SomeObject` with `MyClass` and leave the other two properties (`String a` and `Integer b`) unset.  The caveat is that you would have to use setter injection instead of constructor injection, at least for the properties that aren't set in your context XML file.

**Non-Spring-Managed Solution**

If for some reason you need `MyClass` not to be Spring-managed, then I recommend your first approach because it uses weaker coupling between `SomeObject` and `MyClass` than your second approach.  Over-using singletons can lead to confusing code since they are in essence a type of global variable that hide dependencies.  See [here](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/17/singletons-are-pathological-liars/) for a more elaborate argument.